# Why is using cout in a class function considered bad?

Tags: c++, class, cout

The Assignment was to create a PairList class that held a vector of a Pair class. The Pair class is a template class that holds any two variables of one type.

The code prompting that question:

```
template <class T> 
void PairList<T>::printList()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->pList.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << i+1 << ".\t" 
        << (this->pList[i]).getFirst() 
        << "\t" <<(this>pList[i]).getSecond() 
        << endl;
    }
}
```

Something my teacher said about this code:

"One thing I will say about the ones I like is that both **used cout in functions and it doesn't belong.** I would like your input as to why it is not correct and what things could have or should have been done to eliminate the use of cout in these functions
This is a warning for now. In the future I will start docking serious points like the 70% I do in the level 1 class."

He wasn't very specific on what functions he wanted and let us create whatever we thought was necessary. I received an A but wanted to know why I shouldn't use cout in this function.

Why is using cout in a utility function a bad thing to do?
What should I do instead?

I'm sorry this is such an ambiguous question. I realize that after posting. Also I'm overwhelmed by all extremely fast feedback!

Comment: Who said it is a bad thing to do?

Comment: My programming teacher

Comment: "One thing I will say about the ones I like is that both used cout in functions and it doesn't belong. I would like your input as to why it is not correct and what things could have or should have been done to eliminate the use of cout in these functions"

Comment: Because he/she/it wants you to write your code to write to generic `std::ostream&` rather than a specific named output stream. Doing so allows you to *very* quickly tailor your client-code to dump to a file or some other stream output device with literally no changes at all.

Comment: This is too broad to answer. One possible reason is that if you are writing re-usable code and your class's purposes is for some data storage or computation, then keeping that separate from the output means that someone else can use your class in a different program to do the same calculation, but they can choose what to do with the result

Comment: heres my function that uses cout /*

Function: printList()

Description: prints out pairlist to screen

Outputs: PairList to screen

*/

template <class T>

void PairList<T>::printList()

{

                for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->pList.size(); i++)

                {

                                cout << i+1 << ".\t" << (this->pList[i]).getFirst() << "\t" << (this->pList[i]).getSecond() << endl;

                }

}

Comment: In that case, @WhozCraig obviously nailed it.

Comment: Thank you guys I think I now understand why he doesn't want us to use cout! Sorry for my ambiguous question :S

Comment: Well, we got to an acceptable one in the end.

Comment: 10 dollars this is about 'using namespace std'..

Comment: @MarcoA.: Ah, it just got acceptable, and you cast the last vote. The irony (and the timing)!

Comment: @Deduplicator I thought of and realized it that after casting the vote sorry :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that whoever said using cout in a class is bad is thinking that, instead of doing

```
type function () 
{
. . . . 
cout << "WHATEVER" << endl ;
. . . .
}
```

that you should have

```
type function (std::ostream &strm)
{
. . . . 
strm << "WHATEVER" << endl ;
. . . .
}
```

Comment: This is a great opener. It is *begging* for a "You would want this because...." to describe the benefits in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues at play here. Regarding headers, you should not typically place implementation in your header files, so a `std::cout` command would be inappropriate there. Regarding your class, it greatly depends--in some cases, using `cout` in a class function is perfectly fine.

Comment: Depends on what kind of function/class/union, for what reason, has its implementation in the header. Also, it's a bit difficult to place the `inline`-function in the implementation-file and still use it.

Comment: Absolutely, good point-- `inline` functions are a notable exception here. I was reasonably confident that wasn't what OP was referring to but I'm glad you reminded me.